# Android Emulator Error about GLES

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, opengl-es-2.0

I'm developing a game for Android via Andengine. I finished coding my game and it works fine in phone and BlueStacks emulator. But It doesn't work on Android Virtual Device Manager emulator. I'm getting an error which is on picture below.

http://s28.postimg.org/ip2fy8ch9/Capture.png

Comment: Are you using ES2.0 (not sure if Andengine is 1.0 or 2.0)? If so, make sure GPU emulation is enabled and that you are targetting API 15 or higher in the AVD and that you have rev17 SDK Tools installed. More info here http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Google itself, in the official Android documentation, the Android emulator does not support yet the OpenGL ES 2.0 features.

Please refer to this official document.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es20.html

You're using OpenGLES-2 without a doubt.